# How do I set up a postgres connection on airflow for the postgres operator

Tags: postgresql, airflow-2.x

For the rtfm crowd, let me document my suffering.

I went here:
https://betterdatascience.com/apache-airflow-postgres-database/
But my ui has UNAUTHORIZED in pink after I add the info.
[image: pink unauthorized]

I also went here:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/connections/postgres.html

But obvious questions remain.  Which file?  what is the format of the default data.  Why can't I just make a connection string and put it somewhere.

I also read this, which doesn't tell us where to put this information, it only tells us how to programmatically override it.  It did give me this golden nugget:
[image: schema is db]
Which would have been another stack overflow question.

Is there a file I should type my connection information or connection string into that has examples already?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.  There's no secret file like airflow.cfg. It's hidden away a database somewhere I set up long ago familiar to nobody who doesn't do this full time.  To update or add connections, you either have to use the ui, which doesn't work for me, or you have to use the cli and type airflow connections add --conn-uri and the string we all know and love.

Since I wasn't born with the knowledge of all the commands available under the cli, I googled here:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html